# C++ Template Array, passing type

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on a project for a class and am running into a bit of trouble. Our professor has given us the fallowing code

```
//myList.h file
template <class type>
class myList
{
    protected:
        int length;         //the number of elements in the list
        type *items;        //dynamic array to store the elements

public:
    ~myList();  
        //destructor for memory cleanup
        //Postconditions: Deallocates the memory occupied by the items array

    myList();   
        //default constructor
        //Postconditions: creates items array of size 0 and sets size to zero

    myList(int n, type t);  
        //assignment constructor
        //Postconditions: creates items array of size n and type t, sets length to n
}
```

then the constructor code that i created for myList(int m, type t) is:

```
template <typename type>
myList<type>::myList(int n, type t)
{
   length = n; 
   items = new  t [n]; 
   }
```

which i think should work, but the problem that I seem to running into is when i try and call the constructor in my main

```
myList list2(4, int);
```

i get the following errors

```
In file included from testmyList.cpp:1:0:
myList.h: In constructor ‘myList<type>::myList(int, type)’:
myList.h:118:17: error: expected type-specifier before ‘t’
myList.h:118:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘t’
testmyList.cpp: In function ‘void test2()’:
testmyList.cpp:17:9: error: missing template arguments before ‘list2’
testmyList.cpp:17:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘list2’
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

`new` expect a *type*. Not a *variable*

```
template <typename type>
myList<type>::myList(int n, type t)
{
   length = n; 
   items = new  type[n]; 
}
```

Notice that the comment is wrong on class declaration. you should have:

```
myList(int n, type t);  
    //assignment constructor
    //Postconditions: creates items array of size n and type **type**, sets length to n
```

BTW, the *value* `t` is not used in your constructor... I *guess* you are missing some initialization here...

Comment: thanks that solved the problems with the .h file, but i am still getting errors with the .cpp file.

Comment: if you place template class implementation into cpp file, then it wouldn't work. Compiler should see complete template implementation to instantiate template. You should place realization into h file, or include testClass.cpp ( instead testClass.h ) in main.cpp. Read more [here...](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/14272/)

Answer (score 0):

For the immediate problem:

```
template <typename type>
myList<type>::myList(int n)  // declare as explicit!
{
  length = n; 
  items = new  type [n]; 
}
```

usage:

```
myList<int> list2(4);
```

but your code has plenty of problems already and it's moot why toy allocate arrays in a list.

Comment: yes that would work, but i cant change the code the my prof provided. The 'myList(int n, type t);' would this still work?

Comment: it will but if that is the take, you should do something with t. And tell your prof he failed most industry guidelines for passing by value for no good reason

Comment: thanks, any suggestions on what to do with passing the type in main cpp file? when i try `myList<int> list2(4, int)`, it gives me "expected primary expression before 'int' " error

Comment: of course it does, 'int' is not a valid argument, you must pass a value, expression, variable...